# bash: source from URL

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, bashrc, curl

In addition to my own computer, I sometimes use an Ubuntu cluster at my school. Rather than manually keep my .bashrc's in sync, I would like to make the school cluster's .bashrc source my personal .bashrc from DropBox via a URL. However, when I naively try `source http://myurl`, I just get an error: `http://myurl: No such file or directory`. How can I can get bash to source from a script located online?

Worst case, I could curl to a named pipe and source that. Is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use process substitution with `source`:

```
source <(curl -s http://example.com/foo)
```

Note: I consider directly running code retrieved over the internet to be a serious security risk. It's probably less risky if this is done over an internal network (depending on its overall security).

Comment: Clever! Good point though that an attacker could easily feed me any code they want.

Comment: Works on Linux, fails on OSX. Writing to a tempfile for OSX instead.

Comment: @nilbus: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16712206/26428), you might try `source <(curl -s http://example.com/foo | iconv -f windows-1251)`

Comment: That got rid of the error, but the script didn't run still on OSX.

Comment: The part of this that jumps out at me is the fact that I can set a variable from^H^H^H^Hin the main script and call that variable without having to redeclare it in the sourced script. `curl <file> | /bin/bash` won't allow that without exporting the variables.

Comment: fail on bash, success on ksh

Comment: @Miao1007: It works in Bash. You provide no information to use to diagnose why you are having a failure.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: fixed by using `source /dev/stdin <<< "$(curl -s http://xxx.sh)"`, it works fine on both!

Comment: @EdwardAnderson The reason this syntax fails in OSX is because OSX is using `bash 3.2`, which does not support process substitution for `source`. It only works for `bash 4.?` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596123/why-source-command-doesnt-work-with-process-substitution-in-bash-3-2/32596626#32596626

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use

```
curl http://example.com/whatever.sh | bash
```

Comment: That works and it's what I'm currently doing, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way. But maybe this is the best, so if nothing turns up soon I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Also, note that this is going in my .bashrc, so technically your solution is infinite recursion. ;) But I know what you meant.

Comment: Piping commands to `bash` will execute them in a separate process, which makes this method unusable for executing `bashrc`.

Comment: Depends on what the commands are - but yes, sorry I agree